# How to assert grpc method response body

Tags: testing, assert, grpc, grpc-java

I'm verifying response of a grpc service method.
Right now im asserting response by taking out every parameter and verifying it against my expected test parameter.If there are many parameters to assert, it becomes a tedious process.
So im looking for something like 'Json comparator' which will verify my grpc response message with expected message .

I'm also thinking of converting my expected and my actual messages to json and verifying it using json comparator.But this is not straightforward.
So any other thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Protobuf messages override `equals()`, so you can hard-code the expected response message and use normal `assertEquals(expected, actual)` in JUnit.